# iOS ibaction code not being triggered due to segue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I am trying to trigger a segue and move to a new view based on the result of an asynchronous task.

I have setup the segue by connecting a button in my initial view and dragging to the next view.  I have also setup an ibaction on the initial button that triggers the asynch task. I think these two things could possibly be in conflict.

my ibaction code looks like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button clicked");


    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"in process");     
    if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"succcess");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myid" sender:@"success"];
         }else{
            NSLog(@"failure");
         }
    }];
```

only the first button click log prints.  The others do not.

My segue methods do not have any logic.

The segues fire without hitting the performSegue method above.

How can I control the segue transition methods from the button click?

How can I have the signup method be called and then have the segue fire?

Comment: So is `performSegueWithIdentifier` being called in the main thread?

Comment: No.  signUpInBackgroundWithBlock calls it in a background thread.  But it seems the segue is occurring before the signup method is even being called.  How can I have the signup method be called and then have the segue fire?

Comment: No idea.  But you need to do all UI activity in the main thread.